# 2018 story about self-driving cars and the trolley problem

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a story in which a self-driving car is trying to make a decision on who to hit in an inevitable collision but the story keeps expanding on the life of the different characters.

It's quite sad and focused on humanizing the different characters and challenging how we value different experiences and potentials.

I thought it was in the *New Yorker* but I can't find it. It is not *Override* by James Yu or *Variations on the Trolley Problem* by Mark Remy.

Comment: I want to say I've read this one before. Are you certain you read it last year?

Comment: In addition to what Fuzzy said, could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories that you could [edit] into your question? :)

Comment: I've read this recently too. The car was judging the value of the possible victims to society. Can't remember where though. Seems like there was a override for members of the programmers family.

Comment: Pat Cadigan published ["AI and the Trolley Problem" on Tor.com](https://www.tor.com/2018/10/17/ai-and-the-trolley-problem-pat-cadigan/) but I don't think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Did you read it online? In a magazine? Or perhaps a single-author or multi-author anthology?

Comment: Is this science fiction? This is a real problem that self-driving cars have to resolve now.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You're probably thinking of this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195720/short-story-about-a-self-driving-car-accident-where-the-cars-cannot-harm-the-cre She says it's not "Override".

Comment: @Ayshe you are 100% correct! Thanks.